# R: Plot Polynomials in R

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to make a plot of the following function :

```
 y =  x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x +1
```

[image]

I tried to recreate this same plot using R:

```
x = seq(from = -5, to = 5, by = 0.1)
y <- x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x +1
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

However, the graph I made in R does not look like the original graph.

Can anyone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your x-axis limits are different to the example - if you change them to "-1.2 : 1.2" the plots look the same:

```
x = seq(from = -1.2, to = 1.2, by = 0.1)
y <- x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x + 1
plot(x,y)
```

[image: example_1.png]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to define a function and use `curve` to take care of the details such as the `x` increments.

```
f <- function(x) x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x + 1
curve(f, from = -1.3, to = 1.2)
```

`plotmath` will put a title like the one in the question.

```
curve(f, from = -1.3, to = 1.2, main = expression(paste("Graph for ", x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x + 1)))
```

[image]